# VBA excel - Is there any way to ensure the user cannot call/run a macro in the immediate window?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

So I have written a VBA application and locked the VBAProject (unviewable).  But of course, the user can still have access to the Immediate Window (if they open another excel file for example and click on my VBAProject, even if locked).  Despite my VBAProject being locked and unviewable, the user, with another excel open, can have access to my Immediate Window and try to run my macros or punch in some codes to run.  Of course, they don't know how I named my macros, but probably can run a code to get the list of names (procedure names).  So - possible to prevent a user from running any code or calling any macro in my VBAProject immediate window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: Use the `Private` keyword.

A longer answer: the only way you can protect your source code is to never release it.

The long answer: It is possible to create a VBA project that actively blocks access to the VBA editor; but this is unethical and it does not protect your source code any more than a project password.

Consider the age old `Workbook.Close` prank that closes a workbook immediately after it is opened.  All the user needs to do is disable macros and reopen the workbook.  The same holds true for anything you write in VBA.  If you're relying on VBA to perform your security action then your security ends when macros are disabled.

Compare that to the security you get with a project password.  Sure, breaking the password is trivial to most developers, but it requires more effort and will stop most casual users.  Importantly, it keeps you and your software on the respected side if the line.

There is a conversation to have about using external tools in lieu of, or in conjunction, with VBA but this is substantially more complicated than the question you asked.  This would also meet any definition of term malware if they behave like you propose.

Comment: Thank you very much, ProfoundlyOblivious!  Your knowledge-sharing provides me with a better understanding of protecting a VBA project.